# How to lookup based on two rows and a column in Google Sheets?

Tags: arrays, lookup

I need to lookup a value based on one column criteria and two row criteria, have tried multiple filter/hlookup formula but keep getting errors and I'm not sure why. I am sure I am just missing something but sure I have done this on excel with no issue.

Any help would be appreciated!

[Sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11sMcgb5uPwLPpTfRRjV0MaWeSyMc7HDuIiiEPWVXvW4/edit?usp=sharing)

As above the hlookup and filter aren't giving me results but not sure why.